# Limit problem using sequential criteria for limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

> $$\lim(n+n^2\log \frac{n}{n+1})= \frac12$$

How?

In the text book it is simply said that this happens by Sequential criteria of limits. I don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Taylor series approach

$$ (n-n^2\ln(1+1/n)) = n-n^2\left( \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\frac{1}{3n^3} -\dots\right). $$

Can you finish it now?

**Note:**

1) The Taylor series of $\ln(1+t)$ at $t=0$ is given by

> $$ \ln(1+t) = t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}-\dots\,. $$

2)

> $$ \ln(\frac{n}{1+n}) = -\ln( \frac{1+n}{n} )$$

Comment: Yes, I got in now. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Diya: You are welcome.